# ブラックリストにあるURLの通信制御

Tags: network, security, browser

メールなどからエクセルやwordファイルが送られてくると思うのですが、ITリテラシーが低い方だとそれをダウンロードをし、閲覧してしまうと思います。
そこまでは良いのですが、閲覧したときに「マクロを有効化しますか」と表示された際、間違えて有効にしてしまう人がいます。それが原因でマクロからマルウェアがダウンロードされ、PCが感染してしまう可能性があります。
それを防ぐために、マクロを有効化しても危険なURLがある場合は、ダウンロードしないようにネットワークを切断したいと思ます。

対象のブラウザは、ChromeとIEとFireFoxです。
OS環境はWindows、URLは絶対パスの対象を拒否したい、対象はプログラムを実行したマシンです。

Comment: どのような回答を求められているのでしょうか？ また暗号化された通信についてはどうお考えでしょうか？

Comment: お使いになれる開発言語をリストアップしてください。そうすれば適切なアドバイスが得られると思いますので。

Comment: `不正な`がどのように判断するのかも分かりませんね。

Comment: `不正なURLに対してリクエストを送るエクセルのマクロを検知する方法` 、と読み替えるのが自然に思います。不正かどうかはホワイトリストが妥当でしょうか。

Comment: 「パケットフィルタリング」というのは主にルータなどのネットワーク機器が行う印象が強く、これと「エクセル(VBA,マクロ)」、「プログラミング言語」がどう結び付くのかがうまくイメージできません。

Comment: `通信の内容を確認して遮断` 、よりも `Excelファイルの中身を確認して削除・通知などの対応` の方が一般的で作成も簡単なように思うのですが、前者の方式にしなければならない強い動機があるのでしょうか？

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/)に陥っている気がしますので、一度本当にやりたいことを整理して質問を修正しては如何でしょうか？

Comment: 質問を編集したのでよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6):

Siegさんも指摘されているようにXY問題に陥っているかもしれません。
とりあえず、今どきのWebブラウザーには

- Internet Explorer 8 以降の[SmartScreen](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/safety/terms/smartscreen.aspx)
- Googleの[セーフ ブラウジング](https://www.google.com/intl/ja/chrome/privacy/#safe-browsing-practices)

などが組み込まれているため、質問者さんがブラックリストを入手するよりも早くこれらに登録され、Webブラウザーは問題のサイトを自動的にブロックします。

またネットワークを切断しようにも暗号化の問題があります。例えば

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com

は別のサイトですが、どちらも 151.101.1.69:443 でつながります。通信内容は暗号化されているため、外部からはこのIPアドレスとポート番号しか確認できず、どちらのサイトにアクセスしているかすら把握できません。今どきは暗号化も無料ででき、マルウェアを特定するのが困難かもしれません。

---

> メールなどからエクセルやwordファイルが送られてくると思うのですが、ITリテラシーが低い方だとそれをダウンロードをし、閲覧してしまうと思います。
>   そこまでは良いのですが、

よくありません。VBAとはいえ既にマルウェアをダウンロード・実行しており感染済みです。追加モジュールをダウンロードするとは限りません（というか質問本体の追加ダウンロードはしない方が多いのでは…？）。

> 閲覧したときに「マクロを有効化しますか」と表示された際、間違えて有効にしてしまう人がいます。

であれば、例えば警告せずにマクロを無効化する設定に変えてはどうでしょうか？